# Create a CvMat object from an IplImage

Tags: opencv, bounding-box, iplimage

I am trying to create a bounding box around a feature in a binary image using OpenCV. I've read that if I create a CvRect object by passing a CvMat object as an argument to cvBoundingRect(), I can obtain the bounding box I seek. My problem is how do I create the CvMat from an IplImage. The line I'd like to use is:

CvMat *imageMatrix = cvCreateMat(int rows, int cols, int type);

but clearly that doesn't accept an IplImage as an input. Is there another way of creating a CvMat from an IplImage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for [cvGetMat](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#getmat) function.

Answer (score 0):

`cvBoundingRect` dose not take a image as parameter but a point set. It seems you should firstly generate a point set from your image and then call `cvBoundingRect`.

To get `CvMat` header from a `IplImage`, you can do as Kamaev has answered.